# How to use OR with grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I ran `grep 'd(o|i)g' a.txt` and a.txt contains `dig` but nothing was returned. Is this the right way to match `dog` or `dig`?

Comment: See also [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373), though the fact that alternation (`|`) only works in ERE is kinda there in the middle of all the other stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `d(o|i)g` is the correct way to do it.  You can also do `d[oi]g` since you are dealing with single characters.

You need to use the `-E` flag on your grep call to get extended regexes.

```
$ cat a.txt
bird
dog
cat
dug
$ grep 'd(o|i)g' a.txt
$ grep -E 'd(o|i)g' a.txt
dog
```

Comment: Standard way of doing it for this particular case: `grep -e dog -e dig a.txt` or `grep 'd[io]g' a.txt`, as you propose.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the regex meta characters, like

```
> echo dig | grep "d\(o\|i\)g"
dig
```

, or you can switch to ERE ("extended RegEx"es):

```
echo dig | grep -E "d(o|i)g"
dig
```

Comment: `\|` with Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) is a GNU extension. POSIX BRE don't have an alternation operator. POSIX EREs (with `grep -E`) do.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try `grep 'd[io]g'` but this only works for single characters.